# Reescrever números de no máximo 2 dígitos do input para o output

Tags: c

Preciso reescrever números de no máximo 2 dígitos do *input* para o *output*, parando de processar o *input* depois de ler o número 42.

**Input:**

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 88
> 42
> 99
> ```

**Output:**

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 88
> ```

Meu código está assim, não consigo entender o que está errado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a=100;
    int *n=(int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        scanf("%d", &n[i]);
        if(n[i]==42){
            a=i++;
            break;
        } 
    }

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        printf("%d\n", n[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: qual o erro? qual a saída quando você executa?

Comment: Também não vejo nada de errado, a única coisa que reparei é que ele permite a impressão de números com mais de 2 dígitos, exemplo 999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parando de ler depois de ler o número 42, entao a sua repeticao nao deve ter um limite `for(int i=0;i<100;i++){` e sim um laço infinito,
deveria ser algo como : `for(int i=0;i>-1;i++){`

e o seu codigo iria ficar assim

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a=0;
    int *n=(int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i>-1;i++){
        scanf("%d", &n[i]);
        if(n[i]==42){
            a=i++;
            break;
        } 
    }

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        printf("%d\n", n[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

se esse for o erro.

Comment: agora deu certo!!! muito obrigado